# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'messageId' MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[image: http://localhost:55245/Messages/ReplyMessage/39]

This error appears when I'm training to post reply message and insert it in Replies Table using message id , I think the problem from the View when the id is calling

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ReplyMessage", "Messages", FormMethod.Post, new 
{ id = "form-reply-message", messageId = @ViewBag.MessageId  }))
```

Any idea what I should change

Controller Get Method:

```
   public ActionResult ReplyMessage(int? Id, int? page)
    {

        MessageReplyViewModel vm = new MessageReplyViewModel();

        if (Id != null)
        {

            var replies = dbContext.Replies.Where(x => x.MessageId == Id.Value).OrderByDescending(x => x.ReplyDateTime).ToList();
            if (replies != null)
            {
                foreach (var rep in replies)
                {
                    MessageReplyViewModel.MessageReply reply = new MessageReplyViewModel.MessageReply();
                    reply.MessageId = rep.MessageId;
                    reply.Id = rep.Id;
                    reply.ReplyMessage = rep.ReplyMessage;
                    reply.ReplyDateTime = rep.ReplyDateTime;
                    reply.MessageDetails = dbContext.Messages.Where(x => x.Id == rep.MessageId).Select(s => s.MessageToPost).FirstOrDefault();
                    reply.ReplyFrom = rep.ReplyFrom;
                    vm.Replies.Add(reply);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                vm.Replies.Add(null);
            }


            ViewBag.MessageId = Id.Value;
        }

        return View(vm);
```

Controller PostMethod :

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult ReplyMessage(MessageReplyViewModel vm, int messageId)
    {
        if (vm.Reply.ReplyMessage != null)
        {
            Models.Reply _reply = new Models.Reply();
            _reply.ReplyDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            _reply.MessageId = messageId;
            _reply.ReplyMessage = vm.Reply.ReplyMessage;
            dbContext.Replies.Add(_reply);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Message");
```

View :

```html
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ReplyMessage", "Messages", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form-reply-message", messageId = @ViewBag.MessageId  }))
{
 if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
 {

 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

 }
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Reply.MessageId);
 @Html.TextAreaFor(p => p.Reply.ReplyMessage, new { @rows = 2, @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reply.ReplyMessage)

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-success" value="Reply" id="btn-reply-message">

 }
```

Comment: Why is the ID nullable in GET but not in POST? Also, in the GET method you fill the ViewBag only if the ID has value. Is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to bind it using [FromQuery] attribute here:

```
public ActionResult ReplyMessage(MessageReplyViewModel vm, [FromQuery("messageId")] int messageId)
{
    ........
}
```

This attributes reads the values after the "?" operator in the URL.  Hopefully it will help!